# Query works at the console but not in code

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My DynamoDB table `alexas` has this item with key "abc" as seen in the DynamoDB console below:

[image]

However, the following query returns no result:

```
const params = { TableName: "alexas",
  KeyConditionExpression: "deviceId = :deviceId",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":deviceId": "abc"}
}
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

The above code returns `null` for `err` and in `data`:

```
{ Items: [], Count: 0, ScannedCount: 0 }
```

I am new to the DynamoDB style of expressions. Is there anything wrong with my code which I took from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html).

If instead of `query`, I used the `scan` method and just have `TableName` in `params`, I get the items in my table. This confirms that I am performing the operations on the correct table that has data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query returned no data because the key value does not match.

The item's `deviceId` is the string `"abc"` and not `abc`. Note the extra quotation marks.

The item was inserted using the DynamoDB console's Create editor and there is no need to include `""` if the value is already expected to be of type string.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB's `Scan` operation doesn't take a `KeyConditionExpression` - only the `Query` operation takes this parameter. Scan always scans the entire table, and has a `FilterExpression` to post-filter these results (however please note that you still pay for scanning the entire table).

For example, here is the official documentation of Scan: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

Comment: You are right. I have changed the GUI to Query, and it's the same, with one row of result for `deviceId="abc"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check [QueryAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

```
const params = { TableName: "alexas",
  KeyConditionExpression: "deviceId = :deviceId",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":devideId":{
       S: "abc", // here
     }
  }
}
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

`ExpressionAttributeValues` needs to be passed in a different manner.

**Update:**
Try using Exp attribute names, (I'm not sure if this will make a difference)

```
var params = {
     TableName: "alexas",
     KeyConditionExpression: "#d = :dId",
     ExpressionAttributeNames:{
          "#d": "email"
     },
     ExpressionAttributeValues: {
           ":dId": "abc"
     }
};
```

Comment: With your method, I get `One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type`. My partition key is type string.

Comment: Can you check the create table script or check data type of the device field ?

Comment: The Table Details say `Primary partition key: deviceId (String)`

Comment: ok. try using exp attribute name with the query(updated the ans with it). If you have dynamodb local setup I'd suggest to debug the query on it.